# Is it really true that no RedHat fix exists for this High/Important 3-month old glib issue?

Tags: rhel, vulnerability, glib

### Short version

Red Hat Customer Portal lists [CVE-2021-27219](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2021-27219) as having a 9.8 out of 10 RedHat CVSS score, that it was published February 4, 2021, more than 3 months ago and that it affects RHEL 8, the newest version.

Is there really no fix for it out yet?

### Longer version

If I read the above link correctly, the issue affects RHEL 6, 7 and 8 but no fix exists yet. (As opposed to e.g. [CVE-2021-3326](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2021-3326) where a fix was released yesterday).

At the same time, Red Hat's [ubi8/ubi-minimal](https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/ubi8/ubi-minimal/5c359a62bed8bd75a2c3fba8) docker image, updated today shows:

> Health Index "A"(green) (This image does not have any unapplied Critical or Important security updates.)

When I upload that image to our [Harbor Registry](https://github.com/goharbor/harbor), it scans the image and lists it as having CVE-2021-27219 unfixed. Digging into RedHat's own data, it looks like I have to agree with Harbor.

But then I find it highly misleading for RedHat to list the image as having: Health Index "A". Sure there is no *unapplied* fix, because the fix doesn't exist yet, but how can an image be healthy with a 9.8 score unfixed security issue *for 3 months*?

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Are there any popular applications that use the mentioned functions in a way that would lead to an exploitable system? RH may have decided to just ignore it until they can ship new versions of glib (which fix the issue).

Comment: This can lead to loss of service but (from a cursory glance) not a security issue, so it's not getting the same urgency.

Comment: I would classify loss of service as a security issue; I feel like most businesses would as well.

Comment: The question title says "critical" yet I don't see that word appear on the linked page?  I note Redhat have bumped up its importance over NVD.

Comment: @PhilipCouling: https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln-metrics/cvss has a "CVSS v3.0 Ratings" section defining Critical = 9.0-10.0. RedHat has itself bumped the CVSS score for this issue til 9.8 (Critical) from NVD's original 7.5 (High), because: "Confidentiality, Integrity and Availability all set to High because this integer truncation flaw could result in out-of-bounds write, which could be abused to execute code on the system with the privileges of the application linked against glib."

Comment: @A.B: RedHat's CVE page linked above states "... which could be abused to execute code on the system with the privileges of the application linked against glib." - I interpret that as a security issue not "merely" loss of service.

Comment: I'd still challenge your question title.  Redhat rate this as `Important Impact` not `Ciritcal Impact`.  So Neither NVD's 7.5 nor Redhat's own classification of this claim it is critical.

Comment: @PhilipCouling: I've changed the title, as I can see your point. I find it strange that RedHat themselves raise the CVSS score to 9.8 (98% of max), yet still classify it as Important and not Critical. Oh, well. Thank you for your inputs.